# C# can access Magento 2 SOAP API without OAuth token

Tags: magento2, soap

I'm trying to connect a PC client application written in C# to a Magento 2 demo shop I'm hosting in a Linux VM.

I added a new integration in Magento and activated it, so I got the OAuth tokens the documentation says is required. Then I added a new service reference in Visual Studio to my Magento API with service `catalogProductRepositoryV1`.

I put some effort into adding the required header to the WCF communication and testet the `catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList` call, which returned all of my demo products alright. I then commented out the block that adds the authorization header: **It still works**! I even revoked all access rights for the integration in Magento - no change. I can still list all items.

How can that be? Or is authorization only required upon setting things? Or is it only required upon retrieving information that is otherwise not publicly visible?

The following code is used to demonstrate this:

```
using (client = new Magento.catalogProductRepositoryV1PortTypeClient())
{
    /*using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
    {
        MessageHeader head = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Authorization", "", String.Format("Bearer {0}", "..."));
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(head);
    }*/

    Magento.CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetListRequest r = new Magento.CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetListRequest();
    r.searchCriteria = new Magento.FrameworkSearchCriteriaInterface();
    r.searchCriteria.pageSize = 50;

    Magento.CatalogProductRepositoryV1GetListResponse response = client.catalogProductRepositoryV1GetList(r);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

By browsing the REST API documentation I noticed that some `GET` calls on APIs for public data (such as categories, items, etc.) don't return an `unauthorized` error, while other calls on sensitive data like order items do also return errors for `GET` calls.

Maybe my suspicion is correct and data that's public anyway is not protected by authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your suspicion is correct and data that's public anyway is not protected by authorization (for resources marked with anonymous role)

Comment: I consider this highly dangerous. While the idea of letting the API access public data without authorization seems to be ok, I noticed that the API also lists items that are deactivated in the shop. That way *anyone* could get information about items that are being prepared for the shop while they are unfinished. Or does it?

Comment: You can create issue on github and discuss this with Magento Product Owners.

Comment: I know. I just wanted to leave this as a comment :-)