# How to get the data from Magento2 Soap api using c# program along with wsdl link?

Tags: magento2

I followed the same steps as he followed from the below link

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98845/c-can-access-magento-2-soap-api-without-oauth-token/101527#101527
```

But it not get the data. It causes "An unhandled exception of type '**System.ServiceModel.FaultException**' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Operation "**VsDebuggerCausalityData**" not found" exception. Pls refer the image also.

I referred below sites

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123153/how-to-remove-vsdebuggercausalitydata-header-section-from-soap-request-in-wcf
```

they asked to add the mentioned lines to the app.config file.

I too did but the same error is existing. Kindly help me or instruct me how to get the data from Magento2 Soap api with c# program. Please post step by step instruction with images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To remove `VsDebuggerCausalityData` error you need to go to your Visual Studio Folder

**For example**  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`for Visual Studio 2012 and then run this command `vsdiag_regwcf.exe -u` that will remove

The `VsDebuggerCasualityData` section that was being added to the request coming from the WCF client.

For more info go here: [how to remove vsdebuggercasualitydata from a soap request](https://aspdotnetdevelopment.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/how-to-remove-vsdebuggercausalitydata-from-a-soap-request/)